# $\frac{dz}{dt}$ where $z=f(x,y)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, chain-rule

I'm trying to differentiate the function $$z = x^3-y^3$$ where $$ x = \frac{1}{1+t}, \ \ \ \  y = \frac{t}{t+1}$$

I remember there being a proper way to do this using partial differentiation, but I decided to take a stab at it by expressing $x$ and $y$ in terms of $t$ and differentiating it explicitly. Prepare for some messy maths. Hopefully I didn't make any mistakes here, but the point is whether my approach is a valid one:

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} [(\frac{1}{1+t})^3] - \frac{d}{dt}[ (\frac{t}{t+1})^3]$$

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = [3(\frac{1}{1+t})^2 * \frac{d}{dt}[(1+t)^{-1}]] - [3(\frac{t}{t+1})^2*\frac{d}{dt}[\frac{t}{t+1}]]$$

$$\frac{dz}{dt} = [-3(\frac{1}{1+t})^2*(\frac{1}{1+t})^{2}] - [3 (\frac{t}{t+1})^2 * (\frac{1}{t+1})^2]$$

Erm.. hopefully this isn't too hideous but this is what I have. Is this approach invalid or a poor idea, and if so, why?

Comment: It looks like you've done it correctly, but the fact that it's ugly is exactly why the chain rule is usually invoked on these kinds of problems.

Comment: You might be better off substituting before differentiating.  i.e. $z = \frac{1-t^3}{(1+t)^3}$

Answer (score 1):

Your approach is valid, but it might help to use the chain rule. A shorter version of your answer is$$
\frac{dz}{dt}=-\frac{3(1+t^2)}{(1+t)^4}.
$$

Comment: Could you run by me solving this using the chain rule?